# How to duplicate cloudera impala table with impala-shell or other means?

Tags: cloudera, impala

I see a table "test" in Impala when I do show tables;

I want to make a copy of the "test" table so that it is an exact duplicate, but named "test_copy". Is there a impala query I can execute to do this? If not, how can I do this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use the `"CREATE TABLE test_copy LIKE test"` to create a table with the same metadata. Then you can use `"INSERT INTO TABLE test_copy SELECT * FROM test"` to copy the data.

Answer (score 9):

You can do this by a single command:

`CREATE TABLE new_table AS (SELECT * FROM table);`

Comment: While this will duplicate the data, it does not maintain the definition of a parent table and defaults to `STORED AS TEXTFILE`.